# Google Analytics Event Tracking on Form ID. Not Sure If It is correctly Installed or not?

Tags: javascript, forms, events, analytics, tracking

I am tracking Form Submission leads through Event triggering on my Google Analytics account. The Form in website is built in such a technical way that Form submission is happening through "Submit" tag, instead of normal "Click" way. The source code image of my form's submit button, may help you in getting this. Please use below link to open the image, as StackOverflow is not allowing me to post the images:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4ltjs46knjwcrc/Event%20Tracking%20Code%20Example.png

Due to the nature of form, I have placed the "OnSubmit" Event tracking code in the Form ID tag of the source code. Again, please use the below link to open the same:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/443fzcz6a6jrfsu/Form%20Submit%20Tag.png

Now, my query is, have I installed the event tracking code properly? I mean, would this event be triggered, when someone submit form on my website successfully?

This is running since a couple of days and I have been reporting the leads as well in my GA account through this event, but not getting the leads in the inbox. When checked with my technical team, they said there might be server issues, due to which the lead information is not coming to inbox.

I am not sure, whether it is a server error causing leads information going somewhere else other than inbox, OR it is an wrong event tracking that is showing me wrong numbers??

Can anyone please help me on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question about the tracking code being installed properly could be possible, it justs depends on your kind of implementation. However, do note that Google recommends to add a slight delay between the moment the action takes place (in your case, the form being submitted) to the moment that Google can receive the event in order to be logged.

Consider about adding a small delay before your form gets sent. [Take a look at this recommendation from the Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en).

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your response. The link is resourceful. My form submission is exactly having a few sec's delay in its submission.

Comment: @ashokpatidar it shouldn't be any problem then. If your Google Analytics account is indeed receiving all those events, there's no problem between your site and GA. If you're not receiving the events in your Inbox (assuming "email" here) you might want to re-configure the emails being sent by Google to your e-mail.